# Retrieve instagram access token on page load

Tags: c#, instagram

I want to show my user feed on my website and what I intend to do is to authenticate my own user account each time a user visits the page, and in that way buypass that the user have to log in to his instagram account.

My problem is that I'm having a hard time retrieving the instagram access token through a HttpWebRequest..

See the following NON working code sample:

```
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("https://api.instagram.com/oauth/authorize?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&redirect_uri=http://mywebsite.com&response_type=token");
    request.Method = "POST";
    request.AllowAutoRedirect = false;

    HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

    string redirectUrl = response.ResponseUri.ToString();

    HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(redirectUrl);
    HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

If I paste the url in my browser I get a redirect to http://mysite.com/#access_token=xxxxxxxxxxxxxx and everything seems fine, but when I try to execute the code above, I can't retrieve the correct uri due to some in between redirects before the final url.

Any help would be much appriciated..

Comment: did you get this code working? Got the exact same issue now in my code and can't find a solution for this..

Answer (score 1):

I recommend you to use [Instasharp](http://instasharp.org/) library. InstaSharp is a C# library that wraps the Instagram API and makes it easy to write applications with Instagram data. It has a very easy method to get access token for a user. Check its API.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the documentation for Instasharp currently provided has a few errors. I.e. The documentation says OAuthInfo, when such a class does not exist. 
Here is some code that works for me. 
Notice you don't seem to need to pass a User Object at all (not sure why you would need to anyway)
Also note, that the authenticated and non authenticated methods allow you pass different params, count being the most important one. I've noticed that regardless of the count you pass, an arbitrary number of results is returned, e.g. 33 for authenticated and 13 for authenticated for the same search term. InstagramResult is my wrapper class for the object and Config holds the InstagramAuthorisationModel and InstagramAuthorisationModel holds the static keys created when signing up for a developer account.

```
 public class InstagramService : IInstagramService
 ...
 public InstagramConfig Config
    {
        get{return new InstagramConfig("https://api.instagram.com/v1", "https://api.instagram.com/oauth", InstagramAuthorisationModel.ApplicationId, InstagramAuthorisationModel.Secret, InstagramAuthorisationModel.RedirectUri);}
    }
  private AuthInfo UserAuthInfo()
    {
        return new AuthInfo()
         {
             // User =new UserInfo(){},
             Access_Token = GetInstagramAccessToken()
         };
    }

   public string GetInstagramAccessToken()
    {
        return _socialMediaRepository.GetInstagramAccessToken(_userApiKey);
    }

   public List<InstagramResult> Search(string searchTag, int count)
    {
        var auth = UserAuthInfo();
        var tags = new InstaSharp.Endpoints.Tags.Authenticated(Config, auth); 
        var searchresult = tags.Recent(searchTag);
        return searchresult.Data.Select(media => new InstagramResult()
        {
            Media = media,
            image = media.Images.LowResolution.Url
        })
        .ToList();
    }
```

..